# How to select closely spaced objects in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, selection-tools, select

In Blender 2.8 when two or more objects is close to each other you can click near some of it couple times and selection will be toggle between those objects. How can I do the same to select closely spaced objects in Blender 2.8? Gif file attached

[image]

Comment: This works for me in 2.8. Have you changed any viewport setting or opened an old file?

Comment: Thanx for answer... I try clear version of blender, yes it works but not good as in Blender 2.79... I mean I have to click 3-4 times and only after that Blender will toggle selection to another object see the gif file by the link
https://yadi.sk/i/TGbNcsgk_-gEOA